# Omniauth Facebook: redirect after sign-up doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sign-up page, which is basically a two-step form, I created with wicked gem. After sigh-up a new user gets re-directed to a a profile page, which needs to be created in order to use the website. Here are the contorollers I have regarding these steps: 
Users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
  end

end
```

Registrations:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
  super
end

def create
  super
end

def update
  super
end

protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        user_steps_path 
    end

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        user_steps_path
    end
end
```

User Steps:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :address


    def show
      @user = current_user
      render_wizard
    end


    def update
      @user = current_user
      @user.update!(user_params)
      render_wizard @user
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
    end

    def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil, params = nil)
        redirect_to new_user_profile_path(current_user)
    end

end
```

And now finally my Omniauth Callbacks Controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Unfortunaltelly the re-direct doesn't work. Basically I tried to change it to the path I actually need and which also works with the "normal" sign-up :

```
redirect_to new_user_profile_path(current_user)
```

But this leads me to the following localhost page:

```
http://localhost:3000/#_=_
```

Actually any path I am trying, will lead me to this, after facebook sigh-up. I cheked facebook for developers and as I understood it, if there is an actual hosting, you can change the redirection path. Is it also possible for developing phase, while working with localhost? This would be great! Thanks.

Comment: As for working with localhost and omni auth that requires https, you can download `ngrok` it's a tunneling app that will allow the use of https for testing locally

Comment: what you do in your controller is correct as far as I can tell (I actually have a project using Users::OmniauthCallbacksController the same way you do) and I suspect there might be something in between that is interfering. Is your code getting to the point where you get into @user.persisted? if block?

Comment: Yes, I can sign up and the user is being saved to the DB, the redirect doesn't work and I also suspect, that this is a localhost problem. However ngrok will not let me check anything, cause it shows the error cause of too many connections

Comment: I could solve it and the ngrok didn't play any role in the end, cause the problem was, that the user got saved, so the redirect never found place. Now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In finding the answer I went a step further, which led me to the following problem. 
[Facebook omniauth redirect_to user_steps_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426896/facebook-omniauth-redirect-to-user-steps-path) .

This I could solve, with changeing the statements in my OmniAuthController. The answer can be found under the link above.