# Facebook omniauth redirect_to user_steps_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multistep form, which is to be filled out upon registration. For this I use the wicked gem and it works good for the sign_up where a User fills out the form by hand. But I also have a Facebook sign_up option, which for now is not working. Here is my User_Steps_Controller

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard
    steps :address


    def show
      @user = current_user
      render_wizard
    end


    def update
      @user = current_user
      @user.update!(user_params)
      render_wizard @user
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :street, :house_number, :city, :zip_code)
    end

    def redirect_to_finish_wizard(options = nil, params = nil)
        redirect_to new_user_profile_path(current_user)
    end

end
```

In my Registrations_Controller I also specified

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 def new
    super
  end

def create
    super
  end

def update
      super
  end

  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        user_steps_path 
    end

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        user_steps_path 
    end
end
```

Now, basically, upon Facebook sign_up I also create a new user, which is being saved with first.name, last.name, email and password.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook]
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
    after_create :create_profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
            name = auth.info.name
            user.first_name = name.split(" ")[0]
            user.last_name = name.split(" ")[1]
    end
    end
end
```

So, now I want to check, if this user didn't fill out the street field, he will be redirected to the second step of the form, so he or she then will fill out the details.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted? && @user.street.blank?
      redirect_to user_steps_path(@user)

    elsif @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This actually leads to the path I wanth: user_steps/address , but shows an error in my view address.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :street %>
        <%= f.text_area :street %>
    </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

It says: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.` But my user is created upon sign_up and id I check in the console this user has been saved to the database. So, why is this error??? I also tried:

```
redirect_to user_steps_path(@user)
redirect_to user_steps_path(user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, as I can guess, that the User comeing from Facebook wasn't assigned to a current_user. This solved it:

```
if @user.persisted? && @user.street.blank?
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to user_steps_path(:new, :user_id => @user.id)
```

So the OmniauthCallbacksControllerlooks like this:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
def facebook
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if @user.persisted? && @user.street.blank?
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to user_steps_path(:new, :user_id => @user.id)

    elsif @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I guess, not all the code lines are needed, but I am a beginner, it works for now, so I will leave it. Feedback is welcome.